# adding a delay after an animation has happened for another one to fire

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about making it so after, let's say 2 seconds the h1 goes back to 50px font-size?

Here is an example I made;
https://jsfiddle.net/bx2cqzgt/7/

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('.hi');

h1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    h1.style.fontSize = '90px';
});
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the setTimeout function? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: You can use setTimeout of 2000 milliseconds, but you can do the same thing with css too.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`setTimeout(function, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to run a provided function after a given delay:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('.hi');
h1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    h1.style.fontSize = '90px';
    setTimeout(()=>{h1.style.fontSize = '50px';},2000);
});
```

```html
  <h1 class="hi">Please click me</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('.hi');

h1.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    targetElement.style.fontSize = '90px';
  setTimeout(function(){
    targetElement.style.fontSize = '50px';
  },2000)
});
```

Comment: `event.srcElement` is deprecated, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Comment: thanks for the update, but still some browser support, that's why I added it.

Comment: Ok, I found it: According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) `srcElement` is required for Internet Explorer versions 6 to 8. But since IE 11 is no longer supported by Microsoft we can now safely stop supporting these even older browser versions too.